# Algorithm to compute the volume of a finite union of overlapping balls?

Tags: computational-geometry

Suppose I have finite list of $n$ balls, specifying their positions and radii. The balls can have non-empty intersections.

Is there an algorithm to compute the volume of the region resulting from the union of all $n$ balls?  How hard is this problem?

Is there a source code out there that does the computation already?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. there is an algorithm with time complexity $O(n)$. Details of implementation and algorithm step in this article: *Computing the Volume of a Union of Balls: A Certified Algorithm* which is implemented in CGAL. For example see [this](https://hal.inria.fr/inria-00409374/document) or [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/29599273_Computing_the_Volume_of_a_Union_of_Balls_A_Certified_Algorithm) as a reference.

Comment: Vorlume is now part of the Structural Bioinformatics Library: http://sbl.inria.fr/doc/Space_filling_model_surface_volume-user-manual.html